# Using curl in shellscript

Tags: shell, curl

I am new to shell script.

I am trying to use one curl request like this in my shell script.

```
curl -X POST --header "Content-Type: application/json" --header "Accept: */*" "http://localhost:8080/api/rest/v1/category/p1/{id}?id=${a}&name=${b}&typecode=${c}
```

where $a or $b or $c may contains words seperated by spaces due to which curl request is getting failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
curl -X POST --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Accept: */*' \
 "http://localhost:8080/api/rest/v1/category/p1/{id}?id=${a// /%20}&name=${b// /%20}&typecode=${c// /%20}"
```

`${a// /%20}` (an similarly for `$b` and `$c`) will replace all space by `%20` (encoded space) so that your rest API gets all parameter values correctly.

Answer (score 2):

You should also be able to **get curl to do the work of encoding** space and other special characters for you in the query string by using `--data-urlencode`, whilst adding `-G` to make it part of the url:

```
curl --header "Content-Type: application/json" --header "Accept: */*" \
"http://localhost:8080/api/rest/v1/category/p1/{id}" \
--data-urlencode id="${a}" \
--data-urlencode name="${b}" \
--data-urlencode typecode="${c}" \
-G -X POST
```

Test by setting `a='a a' b='b b' c='a&b&c'` and adding `-v`. You get the header:

```
POST /api/rest/v1/category/p1/id?id=a%20a&name=b%20b&typecode=a%26b%26c HTTP/1.1
```

By the way, `{}` should be encoded in urls so curl has removed them.